# Load data into Oracle using Python from imeicheck.com API

Tags: python, json, oracle, imei

I'm new to Python, and I want to get IMEI data from https://imeicheck.com/ website, using Python and load it into Oracle DB.
I've 2 issues:

1. provided API link from this website return only the specified IMEI data while I want to get the whole data.

   https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/modelBrandName?imei=352322311421731&format=json
2. when importing to Oracle DB, I receive the below error:

   ```
   DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-4-203f77e9ca0f> in <module>()
         8  models,
         9  model_name) 
   ---> 10 VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4)''',rows)
        11 db.commit()

   DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
   ```

**Here is my code:**

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

url = "https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/modelBrandName?imei=352322311421731&format=json"
response_API = requests.get(url, verify=False)

data = response_API.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

rows = [list(x) for x in df.values]

conn_str = 'bi/testpasss@1.1.1.1:1521/ORABI'
db = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
curs = db.cursor()
curs.execute('truncate table DIM_IMEI')

curs.executemany('''INSERT INTO DIM_IMEI(IMEI,
 brand,
 models,
 model_name) 
VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4)''',rows)
db.commit()
```

I would be thankful if you could assist with these issues.

Comment: Have you even looked at the JSON data you're receiving? You could either print out the dataframe, or print out the data in `rows`. If you did either of these you would clearly see that your dataframe has 6 columns. You are therefore attempting to insert six values using only four placeholders, and of course this is never going to work. If you want further help, you will have to explain which four of these six values should go into your database. And for future reference, doing some basic debugging on your code before posting it on Stack Overflow would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a recent Oracle Database version, then you could simply store the returned data in an Oracle JSON column:

```
import os
import platform
import json

import requests
import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
pw = os.environ.get('PYTHON_PASSWORD')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            cursor.execute("drop table dim_imei purge")
        except oracledb.DatabaseError:
            pass

        cursor.execute("create table dim_imei (j json)")

url = "https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/modelBrandName?imei=352322311421731&format=json"
response_API = requests.get(url, verify=False)
data = response_API.json()

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        connection.autocommit = True
        cursor.setinputsizes(oracledb.DB_TYPE_JSON)
        cursor.execute("insert into dim_imei (j) values (:bv)", [data])

        for r in cursor.execute("select * from dim_imei"):
            print(r)
```

Or if you need to store the values in an existing relational table then something like this might work:

```
import os
import platform
import json

import requests
import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
pw = os.environ.get('PYTHON_PASSWORD')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            cursor.execute("drop table dim_imei purge")
        except oracledb.DatabaseError:
            pass

        cursor.execute("create table dim_imei (brand varchar2(20), models varchar2(20), model_name varchar2(20))")

url = "https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/modelBrandName?imei=352322311421731&format=json"
response_API = requests.get(url, verify=False)
data = response_API.json()
b = data['object']['brand']
m = data['object']['model']
n = data['object']['name']

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        connection.autocommit = True
        cursor.execute("insert into dim_imei (brand, models, model_name) values (:b1, :b2, :b3)", [b, m, n])

        for r in cursor.execute("select * from dim_imei"):
            print(r)
```

You'll have to work out which bits of the returned response you actually want to store.  Using Pandas to do a conversion will just add overhead.

To insert one row I simply use `execute()`, not `executemany()`.  Also I set `autocommit` for this one row to save the extra overhead of an explicit `commit()` call.

Note I'm using the latest version of cx_Oracle, which is now called python-oracledb: see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: My problem was solved by your advice, many thanks and appreciation